# different sha256 hash value of file vs. file contents as WordArray

Tags: javascript, hash, cryptojs, arraybuffer

I made a test text file, the contents are:
`aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbccccccccddddddddeeeeeeeeffffffffgggggggghhhhhhhh`

The sha256 hex digest for this value as a string is:
`75eef9680de51f6f70291057e9afc5975470960dfec5f37f83db69aa625786e5`

I get this same value when hashing it in python using hashlib, js using Crypto.js, or using ssl on the file from the command line.

however, in js, when I read the file in like this:

```
var fr = new FileReader();
fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
console.log(fr.result.byteLength); // it's 64...
var input = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(new Uint8Array(fr.result));
CryptoJS.SHA256(input).toString();
```

I get:
`8f76bf13468fb12ac4e59610adff70fd10282e8494a2749db4677f81e2c6e998`

UPDATE: from the crypto.js docs:

```
/**
 * cryptojs use WordArray (CryptoJS.lib.WordArray) as parameter/result frequently.
 *    A WordArray object represents an array of 32-bit words. When you pass a string,
 * it's automatically converted to a WordArray encoded as UTF-8.
 */
```

suspecting it could be a utf-8 vs ascii thing, or something like that, but have no idea how to check.

Comment: Does the `WordArray` have a `toString` or some other way to print the contents? I imagine you're gaining/losing whitespace or something along those lines.

Comment: it does, and it looks normal: `000000610000006100000061...` to start with.  No whitespace issues, just the expected char codes.

Comment: `readAsArrayBuffer` reads part by part and fires off a `readyState` and `loadend` event when the content is completely read ?

Comment: just a 64 byte file...

Comment: If you're seeing `000000610000006100000061` from the WordArray, it definitely looks like each character is getting padded out with three extra bytes to a 32-bit word. Whether that's UTF-related or an artifact of the crypto lib, I'm not sure.

Comment: Try it like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ftaLL5o0/

Comment: hmm, if that's true, I might be a bit stuck.  I have to start with a Uint8Array, because I am slicing up parts of a file to get the relevant portions to hash.  Crypto.js only operates on strings or these WordArrays.  Any idea how to hash a Uint8Array directly?

Comment: Why can't you use the Uint8Array when slicing, and then convert it to a String (skip using a WordArray) to pass into the Crypto lib.

Comment: I can for the test file - but the real file might be 5-10 Mb - when I try that, I get `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` plus, the data is binary in nature - treating it as text might introduce other problems.

Comment: @adeneo - it makes no difference.  Anyway, I am entering the lines one by one in the console at present - I was manually waiting for returns. your suggestion might be useful in the final implementation, and I appreciate it, but it's not the current issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [asmCrypto.js](https://github.com/vibornoff/asmcrypto.js) which accepts both ArrayBuffers and Uint8Arrays as input - I'm now getting the expected result (It's also pretty fast).  I use it like this:

```
var fr = new FileReader();
fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
console.log(fr.result.byteLength); // it's still 64...
asmCrypto.SHA256.hex(new Uint8Array(fr.result));
asmCrypto.SHA256.hex(fr.result); // this also works
```